# jQuery checking if a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a burger menu using jQuery. And I have also created another jQuery function that automatically scrolls down the page to the anchor position when a link is clicked. Now what I need the burger menu function to do is close when one of the auto_close class links is clicked.

```
<nav>
            <img class="logo_animated" src="images/popsies.svg">

            <ul id="height">
                <li class="auto_close"><a href="#welcomeAnchor">Welcome</a></li>
                <li class="auto_close"><a href="#menuAnchor">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="auto_close"><a href="#timesAnchor">Opening Times</a></li>
                <li id="mob_icons">
                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="mob_contact">Tel: 0113 0000000</li>
                <li class="mob_contact">Email: example@yahoo.co.uk</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

my burger menu function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".burger-button").click(function(){
    $("nav").toggleClass("show");
    $("body").toggleClass("no_scroll");
});
});
```

Comment: *"I have created a burger menu using jQuery. And I have also created another jQuery function that automatically scrolls down the page to the anchor position when a link is clicked. "* **There's no `.burger-button` in HTML, the jQuery does not match the HTML at all. Put your code in a Snippet, and test it.** Haven't downvoted yet, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `show` class reveals the *burger menu*, remove it if any of the `a` elements was clicked.

```
$("#height li a").click(function() {
  $(".burger-button").removeClass("show");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using toggle you can just add a reference to the `.auto_close a` links like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".burger-button,.auto_close a").click(function(){
    $("nav").toggleClass("show");
    $("body").toggleClass("no_scroll");
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks I'll be selecting this as the answer when it allows me

Comment: you should note that every time any of these buttons will be clicked everything will be toggled. you might want to have 2 separate functions that show or hide.

Comment: @Reece But... this code doesn't change anything. It still won't hide the burger **and if it is** - it will just **toggle it**, which means that it will be hidden or unhidden per every click.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way, if your burger is always open, when one of your links is clicked.

```
$('.auto_close').click(function(){
    $(".burger-button").trigger('click')
})
```

else if it isnt sure the burger is always open, just remove the classes

```
$('.auto_close').click(function(){
    $("nav").removeClass("show");
    $("body").removeClass("no_scroll");
});
```